# How to calculate inverse of cumulative doubly non-central f distribution in python

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to calculative the inverse of a cumulative doubly non-central f distribution in python. Scipy does have a non-central f distribution (scipy.stats.ncf) but the documentation is rather poor, and it doesn't seem that nc, the non-centrality parameter, can be a list (to pass the nc for the numerator and the denominator). I know the numerator and denominator are non-central chi squared distributions (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NoncentralF-Distribution.html) but I am not sure how to use this information to find the desired inverse. Anyone know how I might go about the task?

Comment: Nice explanation at :http://home.online.no/~pjacklam/notes/invnorm/

Comment: This is interesting but is an algorithm for the inverse of the cumulative normal distribution no?