# How to calculate doubly-non central cumulative F distribution in Python

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

This is an alternative question to a previous one I asked here:
[How to calculate inverse of cumulative doubly non-central f distribution in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327150/how-to-calculate-inverse-of-cumulative-doubly-non-central-f-distribution-in-pyth)

I found a way to avoid the inverse problem, so I just need to calculate the cumulative doubly non-central f distribution (DNCF) in python. I don't know much about statistics but wolfram indicates the DNCF is just a ratio of non-central chi squared distributions http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NoncentralF-Distribution.html.

Given my DNCF distribution with numerator degrees of freedom and non-centrality parameter (Dfn,Ncn) and denominator degrees of freedom/ non-centrality parameter (Dfd,Ncd) would it be accurate to simply do something like this:

```
def DNCF(x,Dfn,Dfd,Ncn,Ncd):
    out=scipy.stats.ncx2.cdf(x,Dfn,Ncn)/scipy.stats.ncx2.cdf(x,Dfd,Ncd)
    return out
```

This seems like it would work to me, but I would appreciate some verification from someone who knows more about statistics.
Thanks

Comment: No, your proposed formula is incorrect. The cdf of a ratio of variables is generally some more complicated function, as given by the so-called change of variables method (also called the transformation method). Unfortunately, I don't know the right formula. If you can't find it, you can try working it out via change of variables. It will be necessary to do an integration or two to get the cdf -- if you can at least set up the problem, you might resort to some computer algebra system to compute the integrals.

Comment: The Mathworld article to which you linked has a formula for the cdf (they call it the distribution function there). The formula involves a couple of special functions, but I think both the beta function and 2F1 hypergeometric function are included in SciPy.

Comment: I am not sure how I would implement the equation. It might require a cython implementation in order to be efficient (with the summations). I will look more into this, thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe the presence of factorials in the denominator of the terms will make it converge fast enough. Let us know how it turns out.

Comment: The closest I know of this in python is in this thread http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2010-October/026832.html The code uses explicit integration.

Comment: The doubly noncentral F ditribution is well-studied in the following paper:
Chattamvelli R. (1996)
On the doubly noncentral F distribution,
Computational Statistics and Data Analysis, 20, 481-489.
If the denominator degrees of freedom is even, you could use the Laguerre series representation given in that paper.